# How to control and vanish termiticide/pesticide fumes from room

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

I had some wood work done in my room and termiticide (UNIBAN-20 (Chlorpyriphos-20% EC) was used so that there is no termites attack in future. The stupid carpenter was using this product for the first time and it had to be diluted 10 times in kerosene oil before use which he didn't do. He poured the concentrated solution of this termiticide.

Now we have very strong smell and poisonous fumes (the head starts spinning within seconds) in the room.

How can I neutralize the smell and get rid of the poisonous fumes? It has been 13 days now.

I have exhaust fan switched on but the smell is still there in the room.

Comment: I think you should seek professional advice to solve this problem. It doesn't sound like the sort of thing that you want to mess around with.

Comment: @bon: Thanks for your response! Who should i approach?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by bon in the comments, this is probably something you should contact someone who is actually *supposed* to be able to answer this question about. The fumes might just be an annoyance, or they could be highly and immediately dangerous.

One place to start is with the manufacturer. Indeed, the manufacturer is probably the best place to go in general with chemical safety concerns. This chemical seems to be produced by a number of firms, so I was not able to locate a specific one, but a [google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Chlorpyriphos-20%25%20EC%20msds) shows a number of possible contacts. [This MSDS](http://msdssearch.dow.com/PublishedLiteratureDAS/dh_008a/0901b8038008a2ff.pdf?filepath=india/pdfs/noreg/012-70038.pdf&fromPage=GetDoc) provides contact information for a Dow subsidiary. I suspect they will be willing to help, but if they refuse to because they were not the manufacturers of your specific product, you will need to ask the carpenter for the documentation. In a number of locations, the law specifies he must be able to provide an MSDS.

Alternatively, you might wish to contact your local fire department (non-emergency line). They can probably point you to someone local whose job it is to handle potential chemical contamination.

I will note that the MSDS I cited does not suggest extreme danger. However, it is still best to contact a producer or specialist of some sort.